# Appcelerator cloud push notification in iOS

Tags: iphone, cloud, titanium, push-notification, appcelerator

I have implement the cloud push notification in iOS using this tutorial [iOS push notification tutorial](http://blog.teemusk.com/2012/05/building-server-push-notifications-with-appcelerator-titanium-cloud/comment-page-1/#comment-7696). I have did everything as per the above documentation. No error occur while registration.

In cloud console I can see **1 iOS client clients subscribed to push notifications**. Everything seems fine but I cant able to receive the push notification.(even I have restarted my iPhone)

I have sent a push notification  from cloud console, but I cant able to receive the push notification in my iPhone. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct gateway selected on the server side.
The easiest way is to check your mobileprovisioning profile and look for "aps-environment" string. If it is set to "development" you need to use Development (aka Sandbox) gateway. If it is set to "production" you need to use Apple Push Production gateway.

This link might be interesting too:
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/appcelerator-titanium-push-notification/

There are might be VERY small chance that firewall or router blocking push notifications, but this could be easily detected by switching your device from WiFi to 3G.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your certificate. You should enable push notifications in the p12 certificate and it should be configured properly in ACS settings. Please refer [Appcelerator Cloud Push Notification in iOS](http://www.titaniumtutorial.com/2012/07/appcelerator-cloud-push-notification-in.html)